# Testing if the string meets the Right format C++

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to test if a read in string matches the following format, without the use of regex.

The format the code should be in, is:

```
Supplier Reference: XXXXXXX

Date & Time: XXXX

Name of Device: XXXXX

Priority: X

IP Address: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Event ID: XXXXXX

Description of Event: XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I want the code to have a `cout << "Format is incorrect" << endl;`.

This is edit, taken out previous attempt and gone back to basics to explain my logic:

```
using namespace std;

int f;
int main()

{

string mystring;    
ifstream myfile ("test.txt"); 

if (myfile.is_open())

{ while (getline (myfile,mystring))
    {        

        //searches the text entered//
        string search;
        size_t pos;
        {
               //searches the text for the Date entry//
               {
                       search = "Supplier Reference:";
                       pos = mystring.find(search);    
                       {
                           if (pos != string::npos)
                              {
                                   cout<<mystring<<endl;
                                   f=f-1;
                                   }
                              else
                              {
                                  ++f;
                                  }
                              }
               }

               {
                      search = "Date & Time:";
                       pos = mystring.find(search);
                       {
                            if (pos != string::npos)
                           {
                               cout<<mystring<<endl;
                               f = f - 1;
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   ++f;
                                   }
                               }

               }
               {
                      search = "Name of Device:";
                       pos = mystring.find(search);
                       {
                            if (pos != string::npos)
                           {
                               cout<<mystring<<endl;
                               f = f - 1;
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   ++f;
                                   }
                               }

               }
               {
                      search = "Priority:";
                       pos = mystring.find(search);
                       {
                            if (pos != string::npos)
                           {
                               cout<<mystring<<endl;
                               f = f - 1;
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   ++f;
                                   }
                               }

               }
               {
                      search = "IP Address";
                       pos = mystring.find(search);
                       {
                            if (pos != string::npos)
                           {
                               cout<<mystring<<endl;
                               f = f - 1;
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   ++f;
                                   }
                               }

               }
               {
                      search = "Event ID:";
                       pos = mystring.find(search);
                       {
                            if (pos != string::npos)
                           {
                               cout<<mystring<<endl;
                               f = f - 1;
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   ++f;
                                   }
                               }

               }
               {
                      search = "Description of Event:";
                       pos = mystring.find(search);
                       {
                            if (pos != string::npos)
                           {
                               cout<<mystring<<endl;
                               f = f - 1;
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   ++f;
                                   }
                               }

               }
               }
               }
               {
                   if (f>35)
                   cout << f << "Field is missing, Ticket is formatted incorrectly" << endl;
               }
               }
system ("pause");
return 0;                   
               }
```

I know the code is incredibly repetitive. Cheep and Cheerful is what I'm aiming for.

I was hoping someone could let me know how to test for the order of the lines?

Comment: [What is `std::string Date & Time;`????](http://ideone.com/pGb325) Give us compilable codes..

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to read seven lines (one for each line of data). If a line is empty, then discard it and don't count it.

Then for each line, you split it into two strings at the colon `':'`. Use the left part (e.g. `"Supplier Reference"`) as the key into a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) with the right part as data.

Then just loop over the map and make sure that each key matches the needed keys from the file. If a key is missing, or an unknown key is in the map (or if there are not enough lines when reading from the file) your have a format error.